# Encoding Error while writing Pandas Dataframe to PDF using weasyprint?

Tags: python, pandas, weasyprint

I am using [WeasyPrint](https://weasyprint.readthedocs.io/en/stable/index.html) to generate PDF file, The input HTML for `write_pdf` method is produced by [Pandas to_html](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/version/0.23.4/generated/pandas.DataFrame.to_html.html) method as follow:

```
html = open('output.html', 'w+',)
df.to_html(html.name)
HTML(html).write_pdf('output.pdf')
```

But I get the following error:

```
TypeError: Cannot set an encoding with a unicode input, set ['override_encoding', 'transport_encoding']
```

Any I dea how to solve this?

**Note:** The Dataframe object contains data with Arabic language in addition to English.

Comment: Its always good to set the encoding you wish to open with, `encoding='utf-8'` inside the open call.

Comment: I tried that, but the same error still happen.